# Pyspark - getting values from an array that has a range of min and max values

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to write a query in PySpark that will get the correct value from an array.

For example, I have dataframe called df with three columns, 'companyId', 'companySize' and 'weightingRange'. The 'companySize' column is just the number of employees. The column 'weightingRange' is an array with the following in it

```
[ {"minimum":0, "maximum":100, "weight":123},
  {"minimum":101, "maximum":200, "weight":456},
  {"minimum":201, "maximum":500, "weight":789}
]
```

so the dataframe looks like this (weightingRange is as above, its truncated in the below example for clearer formating)

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+--+
| companyId | companySize |     weightingRange     |  |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+--+
| ABC1      |         150 | [{"maximum":100, etc}] |  |
| ABC2      |          50 | [{"maximum":100, etc}] |  |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+--+
```

So for a entry for company size = 150 I need to return the weight 456 into a column called 'companyWeighting'

So it should show the following

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+------------------+
| companyId | companySize |     weightingRange     | companyWeighting |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+------------------+
| ABC1      |         150 | [{"maximum":100, etc}] |              456 |
| ABC2      |          50 | [{"maximum":100, etc}] |              123 |
+-----------+-------------+------------------------+------------------+
```

I've had a look at

```
df.withColumn("tmp",explode(col("weightingRange"))).select("tmp.*")
```

and then joining but trying to apply that would Cartesian the data.

Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Can you show a sample of data? Is this array repeated in each row?

Comment: @mayankagrawal Added samples as requested. The array is repeated for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach like this,

First creating a sample dataframe,

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
        ('ABC1', 150, [ {"min":0, "max":100, "weight":123},
                        {"min":101, "max":200, "weight":456},
                        {"min":201, "max":500, "weight":789}]),
        ('ABC2', 50, [  {"min":0, "max":100, "weight":123},
                        {"min":101, "max":200, "weight":456},
                        {"min":201, "max":500, "weight":789}])],  

        ['companyId' , 'companySize', 'weightingRange'])
```

Then, creating a `udf` function and applying it on each row to get the new column,

```py
def get_weight(wt,wt_rnge):
    for _d in wt_rnge:
        if _d['min'] <= wt <= _d['max']:
            return _d['weight']

get_weight_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y: get_weight(x,y))
df = df.withColumn('companyWeighting', get_weight_udf(F.col('companySize'), F.col('weightingRange')))
df.show()
```

You get the output as,

```py
+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
|companyId|companySize|      weightingRange|companyWeighting|
+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
|     ABC1|        150|[Map(weight -> 12...|             456|
|     ABC2|         50|[Map(weight -> 12...|             123|
+---------+-----------+--------------------+----------------+
```